# Move Magento to another Server

Tags: sql, magento, memcached

I need to move a running Magento 1.9.0.1 installation to another server.
Performing a backup of the Files and the Database ( phpMyAdmin ) does not work for me, I'm just getting critical PHP errors while running the index-file.

I also modified the paths and the website-domain in the SQL-Database.
The file-permissons are correctly set, too.

I've cleared the chache-folders for test purposes but it doesn't work.

The main problem was that there's no local.xml in app/etc/ and the sql-dump was only 3MB small. There was also no sql-host declared in the config.xml-file in app/etc/.

Could the data of the shop be stored in another kind of database?
I think the shop is using memcached but i guess there would only be the sessions stored, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Clear Cache.**

   i) Go to System->Cache Management. Clear caches (Flush Magento Cache, Flush Catalog Image Cache, Flush JavaScript/CSS Cache)

**2. Create zip file.**

i) Backup all your root folder content and make a Zip file. Then upload this zip file to the root in which you want to host your new Magnto store. (Note that you can unzip the file if you have shell access. If you don't have shell access upload the root folder files into new location directly. Only thing is it will take time.)

ii) If your upload completed, using putty unzip the content into the root directory.

**3. Dealing with database.**

i) You can simply export the database from your development environment. But better to run below queries to clear the log files (Note: Only if you are moving from development server to production server. If you are moving live Magento store from one server to other server leave as it is). This will help to reduce the exported sql file size and easy to run on the other server.

```
    TRUNCATE TABLE log_customer
    TRUNCATE TABLE log_quote
    TRUNCATE TABLE log_url
    TRUNCATE TABLE log_url_info
    TRUNCATE TABLE log_visitor
    TRUNCATE TABLE log_visitor_info
    TRUNCATE TABLE log_visitor_online.
```

ii) I guess now you can successfully imported the database in .sql. You can import the database into your new server.

iii) Open your 'core_config_data'. Approximately on 6th and 7th record you can see 'web/unsecure/base_url' and 'web/secure/base_url' whose value will be your current server path. Change it to new server path

**4. Creating database connection.**

i) Open the local.xml located on the physical path  /app/etc/
    ii) You can find your current database connection under  xml tag. Change it accordingly

**5. Indexing.**

i) Login to admin panel on your new server.

ii). Go to System->Index Management and do indexing.

Now all set, if everything would have gone fine, You Magento store will work fine. If not, no worries, check system.log and reports folder inside the var/. Fix the errors.

Comment: Thats what I've already done, it doesn't work for me... Like i described there's no local.xml in app/etc/. There's a app/etc/config.xml  but there is no database configured but the magento-shop is running without problems on the current server. Unfortunately not on the new Server.

Comment: @ManuKILLED without database connection is not possible at all. May be the file is hidden. Create the local.xml file and configure your database.

Comment: Thats the point and there's also no hidden local.xml file in app/etc/. But the shop is running without problems on the current server. Could the database information be in another file?

Comment: @ManuKILLED okay, you create a fresh local.xml copy on your new server and configure try..

Comment: @ManuKILLED assuming it's a linux/unix/bsd based server, try looking for it in the doc root of magento using grep -r 'very_unique_db_name' .

Comment: by the way, i.m.h.o, happend to me once when moving stuff, check the host your working on so you don't switch the old one with the new and keep dumping a brand new empty db.

Comment: A Magento installation running without `app/etc/local.xml`? Spooky! It's getting database connection info from somewhere... Hmm.

Comment: I don't know why but the local.xml and some other files were owned by another user. I haven't had the SSH root login data before so the files were not shown while i was logged in from a user without root access.

It worked for me to zip it via root and take a direct sql-backup. Thank you all very much

Comment: @version.beta it's going perfect, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are not able to take backup from phpmyadmin due to size constrain,
Please use Mysql workbench  for taking database backup, and move the database to the new server, and to install the magento 1.9.0.1 please copy and paste the core version of 1.9.0.1 and install it .and then check the app/etc for local.xml if found. then all was set copy the old magento files and replace it in the new server except the local.xml file, Hope this helps